# Does this sound natural "I want to work long in Japan and make a lot of Japanese friends"

Tags: particle-に

I want to work long in Japan and make a lot of Japanese friends.

日本で長く働き、たくさんの日本人の友達を作りたい。

日本で長く働き、多くの日本人と友達になりたいです。

日本で長く働き、日本人の友達をたくさん作りたいです。

Comment: I would say like `日本で長く働いて、日本人友達をたくさん貰いたいです。`

Comment: ^ You need の: `日本人友達` →日本人の友達. `貰いたい` -- ？ makes me feel like asking 「えっ 誰にもらうの？」

Answer (score 6):

> 日本{にほん}で長{なが}く働{はたら}き、**たくさんの**日本人{にほんじん}の友達{ともだち}を作{つく}りたい。
>
> 日本で長く働き、**多くの**日本人と友達になりたいです。
>
> 日本で長く働き、日本人の友達を**たくさん**作りたいです。

All are grammatical and make perfect sense.

The sentence that would sound at least slightly more natural than the others would be the **last** one.  That is because it uses 「たくさん」 as an **adverb**, which is generally the native speakers' choice.

Japanese-learners have a fairly strong tendency to use number-related phrases as **adjectives** because they are accustomed to saying "make many friends", "eat lots of vegetables", etc. and they naturally attempt to translate those directly into Japanese.

While the same construct is still "grammatical" in Japanese as well, it is not our most intuitive construct choice.

Thus, it is simply more natural and intuitive for us to say:

> 友達をたくさんつくる
>
> リンゴを２個食{こた}べる

than to say:

> たくさんの友達を作る
>
> ２個のリンゴを食べる

I could not even begin to explain how unnatural 「２個のリンゴを食べる」 sounds to the Japanese ears.

Answer (score -2):

作りたい is used to "actually make" something, like 「料理を作りたい」. The exact translation of "Making friends" is not valid here.
While the second sentence is correct, you can also put it in the below way using 「ほしい」:

> 「日本で長い働き、たくさん日本人友達欲しいです。」

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can say 友だちを作る in Japanese.